# ¿Cómo puedo poner diferentes WebView en los fragmentos de una Activity tipo Tabbed Activity con Action Bar?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview

Tengo 3 fragments y quiero que en el primero me muestre un WebView el cual contenga un archivo HTML local. Hasta ahora he logrado que se muestre un WebView pero en el primer fragment a pesar de que la programación está hecha en el segundo, cuando intento poner la misma programación en el primer fragment la aplicación se cierra.

Este el código que tengo en el java del segundo fragment.

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Finformatica2 extends Fragment {

public Finformatica2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String url = "file:///android_asset/denominacionInformatica.html";
    WebView view = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica2, container, false);
}
}
```

Este es el código del java del primer fragment

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

public class FInformatica1 extends Fragment {

public FInformatica1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);
}
}
```

Este es el código del primer fragment

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Este del segundo

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.facien.apliacionfacien.Finformatica2">

</FrameLayout>
```

Este es el código Java de la Activity

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class InformaticaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements             
ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_informatica);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



        }





// Métodos de la interfaz ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

// Métodos de la interfaz ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.

 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
 /**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.

 private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

 public PlaceholderFragment() {
 }

 /**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
/**
 public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
 PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
 fragment.setArguments(args);
 return fragment;
 }

 }
 */

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment tabFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                tabFragment = new FInformatica1();
                break;
            case 1:
                tabFragment = new Finformatica2();
                break;
            case 2:
                tabFragment = new Finforamtica3();
                break;
        }
        return tabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        String section = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                section = "SECTION 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                section = "SECTION 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                section = "SECTION 3";
                break;
        }
        return section;
    }
}
}
```

Adicionalmente a eso tengo un tercer fragment, con esta programación cuando inicia el activity muestra en el primer fragment el WebView, pero cuando me muevo al tercero el WebView desaparece y a pesar de que ponga un WebView en el segundo y tercer fragment solo aparece el del primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque estas creando el WebView en la vista de la actividad no de el fragmento. Recuerda que el método `getActivity` obtiene el contexto de la actividad.

El WebView lo estas creando en la actividad y no en el fragmento y el WebView no existe en el layout de la actividad, por eso te da error. Es como si en la actividad A trataras de crear un `TextView` a partir del TextView que se encuentra en el layout de la actividad B.

Las vistas en los fragmentos se deben crear en método `onCreateView()`, el método `onCreate()` lo utilizas para inicializar variables y otras cosas que no necesiten ser pintadas en la IU.

Y veo que estas enlazando mal los layout con los fragmentos, el layout que contiene el WebView es el que dices que pertenece al primer fragmento. Por lo que ese layout es el que debe estar enlazado con el segundo fragmento.

Sabiendo eso tu WebView en el fragmento `Finformatica2` debe quedar así:

```
public class Finformatica2 extends Fragment {

    public Finformatica2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);

        String url = "file:///android_asset/denominacionInformatica.html";
        WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Y para crear un WebView en cada fragmento. En cada layout de los fragmentos crea un WebView, enlaza esos layout a los fragmentos y crea los WebView en cada fragmento, tal como muestro en el código de arriba.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funcionó así, apenas estoy entendiendo el software, ahora solo me falta hacer que el WebView se muestre completo, porque se corta la parte de abajo.